# Entity Framework Optimize Count Child Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am trying to optimize a query generated with Entity Framework Linq to SQL Query. Below is a massively simplified version of my query.

**C#**

```
List<bool> isUsed = Context.tParent.Select(parent => 
    parent.tChild.Any()
).ToList();
```

This produces the following SQL

**Generated SQL**

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[tChild] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ParentId]
    ))
    ) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[tParent] AS [Extent1]
```

Unfortunately, this performs poorly (my real query checks the count on many linked tables) and if I rewrite the query as follows the speed is greatly increased.

**Optimized query**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (
    COUNT(tChild.Id) > 0
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM tParent
    LEFT JOIN tChild ON tParent.Id = tChild.ParentId
GROUP BY tParent.Id
```

How can I re-write my C# to generate my optimized query using a Linq to SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the following LINQ to Entities query produces effectively the same SQL as your **Optimized query**. It's basically one to one SQL to LINQ translation, but IMO not very intuitive way of describing the query goal. Anyway, here it is:

```
var query =
    from parent in Context.tParent
    from child in parent.tChild.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group child by parent.Id into g
    select g.Sum(child => child != null ? 1 : 0) > 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: I agree this isn't the best way of describing the query intent, but it is performant which for my current task this is more important. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this query return all Parents that at least one child:

```
var result = Context.tChild.Select(child => child.tParent)
    .Distinct().ToList();
```